# Naming a class that decides to retrieve things from cache or a service + architecture evaluation

Tags: architecture, naming, services

I'm a junior developer and I'm working on a pet project that I want to learn as much as possible from.

I have the following scenario:

There's a WCF service that I use to retrieve and update data, lets say Cars. So it's called **CarWCFService**  and has a GetCars(), SaveCar(), ... . It implements interface **ICarService**. This isn't the Actual WCF service but more like a wrapper around it.

Upon retrieving data from the service, I want to store them in local memory, as cache.
I have made a class for this called **CarCacheService** which also implements interface **ICarService**. (I will explain later why it implements ICarService)

I don't want client code to be calling these implementations. Instead, I want to create a third implementation for **ICarService** that tries to read from the **CarCacheService** before calling the **WCFCarService**, stores retrieved data in the **CarCacheService**, etc.

3 questions:

1. How do I name this third class? I was thinking about something as simple as **CarService**. This does not really says what the service does exactly, tho. Is the naming for the other classes good?
2. Would this naming and architecture be obvious for future programmers? This is my biggest concern.
3. Does this architecture make sense? 
   The reason that I implement **ICarService** on the **CarCacheService** is mainly because it allows me to fake the **WCFService** while debugging. I can store dummy data in a **CarCacheService** instance and pass it to the **CarService**, together with an(other) empty **CarCacheService**.
   If I made **CacheCarService** and **WCFService** public I could let client code decide if they want to drop the caching and just work directly on the **WCFService**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this naming and architecture be obvious for future programmers?

To me there are too many Services here. How about

- `CarWCFService` -> `CarWCFAdapter`
- `CarCacheService` -> `CarCache`

Then you can call the third class `CarService` (or `CarServiceImpl` - after all, I assume, clients won't see the name of this concrete class directly anyway, they will only deal with the interface).

Or a different twist: keep `CarWCFService` and call the third class `CarServiceProxy` instead.

> Does this architecture make sense?

I would not have `CarCacheService` implement `ICarService`. The reason you give is a test implementation detail. I would just mock `ICarService` in my unit tests instead. (you do have unit tests, do you?)

Comment: yeah I'm developing this using Test Driven Design for the first time, which forced me to think more careful about this stuff. 
I understand your point and although I said I'd mainly use CarCacheManager for debugging, I think it's also important that people can quickly see how my application works without depending on an external service. The external service actually talks with Active Directory and MS Exchange Server so it would be nice if I can fake this stuff for demos and developing the GUI. What is your reason not to implement ICarService?

Comment: @Thomas, well, is it true that a cache **is-a** CarService? To me it is not. Faking external services in unit tests is what mocks are invented for - use them instead of tangling in your design. There are excellent mocking frameworks around in most major languages.

Comment: I like your naming suggestions, but perhaps CarCacheManager would be more appropriate since CarCache sounds like a class that actually holds the storage, instead of a class that provides an interface with the (memory)storage?

Comment: @Thomas, CarCacheManager would be fine too. Although note that its clients shouldn't care nor know about whether it actually holds the storage or just delegates the work further - it's an implementation detail.

Comment: ok, good point. Thanks a lot for your advice and suggestions. Was certainly helpful.

Comment: @Thomas, my pleasure :-)

Comment: Péter, what do you think about naming CarService CarRepository? Or is a repository not meant to contain as much logic as I want to put in it?

Comment: update: the top rated answer on this link seems to answer it pretty well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440096/difference-between-repository-and-service 
I guess it's very appropriate to name it CarRepository.

Comment: @Thomas, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have two classes, not one. I'd have the cache wrap the DAO. It's essentially the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), where the decoration adds cacheing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim it to be perfect, but I usually call classes that can decide their own cache behavior cacheable_*_* in your case cacheablecarserviceclient would probably be what I call the client piece if I am following your example correctly.